# Unable to setup a DB2 / DashDB JDBC Connection in Apache Airflow

Tags: jdbc, db2, airflow, dashdb

I'm trying to create a DB2 / DashDB connection using the Airflow UI. I have added the db2jcc4.jar driver and provided the path as well as the class name com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.class

I tried to run a simple query (in the ad hoc UI) and always get the same error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Class com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.class not found

Did anybody need to setup a DB2 / DashDB connection in Apache Airflow before?

Found nothing on the web about that.

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify it with ".class"? If yes, did you try just "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"?

Comment: Hey, I tried both ways.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am running into the same issue but with the Netezza JDBC driver.

Comment: Unfortunately not yet. Looks like I'll have to work to implement a DB2 connector for Airflow but I'm not focused on that yet. As a workaround I created some python code to perform the updates in my db2 and called it using the python operator.

Answer (score 0):

May be stupid thing to check but make sure you dont have any leading blank space in connection url, driver path and driver class. Also "airflow" user (or whoever is running airflow process should have access to the driver path.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't still figured this out, I ran into same problem.

With some debugging I came to find that the file `jdbc_hook.py` here https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/jdbc_hook.py#L55
is missing 1 parameter expected in the `jaydebeapi.connect` method call.

In particular is missing the second parameter, which should be the URL of the connection.

I changed the code inside the method `get_conn` to the following to try out, and it worked.

```
  def get_conn(self):
    ......

    conn = jaydebeapi.connect(jdbc_driver_name,
                             host,
                      driver_args=[str(login), str(psw)],
                              jars=jdbc_driver_loc)
    return conn
```

Notice the `host` added to the call to `jaydebeapi.connect`.

I was thinking of opening a PR, but then reviewing, they have already something in a couple of places (search for `jdbc` in Airflow's PRs):

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2227